# Update panel breaking my calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, calendar, updatepanel

The following `asp:Calendar` controls don't seem to want to work inside of the `asp:UpdatePanel` items. By don't work, I mean they are visible, but you cannot change the date or month. Remove the `asp:UpdatePanel` and it works. Is this a known bug? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Anyone have any insight they could offer on this?

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelc" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="centerAlign">
                        <div class="inline">
                            <label ID="lblPostingAvailable" runat="server" class="labelMediumInline">*Posting Available</label>
                            <asp:Calendar ID="calFromDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calFromDate_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="inline">
                            <label ID="lblTo" runat="server" class="labelMediumInline">Posting Expires</label>
                            <asp:Calendar ID="calToDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calToDate_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add:

> > ```
> > <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
> > ```

above the:

> > ```
> > <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelc" runat="server">
> > ```

good luck